# Sending data to store inside looped component gives Invalid hook call

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I created dialog component which can be called globally via redux store. I have been working with Vue before and I would need some help of you guys. When I set data from dialog itself (close dialog by sending false to store) it works fine but when I call from looped component it saying invalid hook call.

Where the hook call must be then, and why?

**Parent** - companies looper through and returned List item (`ListItem` below and `openDialog` function also)

```
{DummyCompany.registerInfo.map((info, index) => {
            return (
              <ListItem
                key={`${index}_${info.label}`}
                message={info.label}
                type={info.type}
                iconRight="notification"
                dialogTitle={info.tooltip.title}
                dialogDescription={info.tooltip.description}
                onClick={() => openDialog(info.tooltip.title, info.tooltip.description)}
              />
            )
          })}
```

**Child** item - Styled div with registration info of company

```
import { FunctionComponent } from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'

import { Spacing } from '../../../shared/enums'
import Icon from '../../Icon'
import Text from '../../Text'
import IListItem from './ListItem.interface'

const Content = styled.div`
  height: 35px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
`

const ListItemIcon = styled.div`
  margin: ${Spacing.Small} ${Spacing.Medium} ${Spacing.Small} 0;
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
`

const ListItem: FunctionComponent<IListItem> = ({
  onClick,
  iconLeft,
  iconRight,
  message = '',
  type,
}) => {
  return (
    <Content>
      {iconLeft ? (
        <ListItemIcon>
          <Icon
            name={iconLeft}
            size={type === 'attention' ? 'medium' : 'nav-item'}
            onClick={onClick}
          />
        </ListItemIcon>
      ) : undefined}
      <Text
        style={{
          fontWeight: type === 'attention' ? '700' : '',
          color: type === 'attention' ? 'black' : '',
        }}
      >
        {message}
      </Text>
      {iconRight ? (
        <ListItemIcon>
          <Icon
            color="blue"
            name={iconRight}
            size={type === 'attention' ? 'medium' : 'nav-item'}
            onClick={onClick}
          />
        </ListItemIcon>
      ) : undefined}
    </Content>
  )
}

export default ListItem
```

Interface where closeDialog method is called from.

```
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { setShowDialog } from '../../redux/slices/dialogSlice'

export const openDialog = (title: string, description: string) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  dispatch(
    setShowDialog({
      showDialog: true,
      title: title,
      description: description,
    })
  )
}
```

**Hook error**

```
react-dom.development.js:16227 Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

Comment: where is `openDialog ` called?

Comment: First code block @devpolo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're initiating a hook `useDispatch` inside a `onClick` handler. This is not allowed, see [the rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html). You should create the `dispatch` in the parent. And dispatch manually from the `onClick`.

```js
function Parent() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  return (
    <>
      {DummyCompany.registerInfo.map((info, index) => {
        return (
          <ListItem
            key={`${index}_${info.label}`}
            message={info.label}
            type={info.type}
            iconRight="notification"
            dialogTitle={info.tooltip.title}
            dialogDescription={info.tooltip.description}
            onClick={() =>
              dispatch(openDialog(info.tooltip.title, info.tooltip.description))
            }
          />
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
}
```

And update your `openDialog` function to return the slice action.

```js
export const openDialog = (title: string, description: string) => {
  return setShowDialog({
    showDialog: true,
    title: title,
    description: description,
  });
};
```

Comment: Now I realized the way it works. Thanks!!